# Vapor upload multiple files at once

Tags: swift, file-upload, vapor

I want to upload multiple images in one POST request. Currently, the part of my request related to the file upload is taking one file and looks like this:

```
return try req.content.decode(File.self).flatMap(to: Image.self) { (file) in
    try file.data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: DirectoryConfig.detect().workDir + localImageStorage + file.filename))
    return try Image(userID: user.requireID(), url: imageStorage + file.filename, filename: file.filename).save(on: req)
}
```

This works just fine. Now, I tried to change `.decode(File.self)` to `.decode([File].self)`, and do a loop for all files.
When trying to upload images using the `data[]` parameter in Postman, I get the following error:

> Nested form-data decoding is not supported.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Downvoters please tell me why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example below works well, tested multiple times already

```swift
struct MyPayload: Content {
    var somefiles: [File]
}

func myUpload(_ req: Request) -> Future<HTTPStatus> {
    let user: User = try req.requireAuthenticated()
    return try req.content.decode(MyPayload.self).flatMap { payload in
        let workDir = DirectoryConfig.detect().workDir
        return payload.somefiles.map { file in
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: workDir + localImageStorage + file.filename)
            try file.data.write(to: url)
            return try Image(userID: user.requireID(), url: imageStorage + file.filename, filename: file.filename).save(on: req).transform(to: ())
        }.flatten(on: req).transform(to: .ok)
    }
}
```

btw also you could declare your payload exactly in the function params

```swift
func myUpload(_ req: Request, _ payload: MyPayload) -> Future<HTTPStatus> {
    let user: User = try req.requireAuthenticated()
    let workDir = DirectoryConfig.detect().workDir
    return payload.somefiles.map { file in
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: workDir + localImageStorage + file.filename)
        try file.data.write(to: url)
        return try Image(userID: user.requireID(), url: imageStorage + file.filename, filename: file.filename).save(on: req).transform(to: ())
    }.flatten(on: req).transform(to: .ok)
}
```

the only difference is in declaring endpoint function on router

```swift
router.post("upload", use: myUpload)
```

vs

```swift
router.post(MyPayload.self, at: "upload", use: myUpload)
```

Then in Postman upload your files like this
[image: PostmanMultipleFiles]

Comment: Awesome, this works really well. Thanks so much! 

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! Let me just note, that I couldn't validate the request if a file is of type `File`. Changing it to `Data` works for validations.