# How to upload files for a model using vapor 3 for an iOS app

Tags: swift, file-upload, multipartform-data, vapor

I want to make an iOS app using Vapor 3 as my backend. The model I am creating to represent my object contains some properties that will be files such as a .png and .plist files. I'm having trouble understanding how to use multipart in order to grab those files and send them to my model endpoint whenever I do a POST request.

I'm also confused on what data type I should be setting those file properties to be in my Model class. In the multipart docs (https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/multipart/overview/#content) under the "Content" section, they say to make a Struct and they set their image to be of type Data, but also say you can make it of type File. I've also seen examples where they make it of type String.

I was hoping someone could clarify what exactly I should set those properties' data types to be and how I could upload those files in my Controllers/ModelController where I do the saving and call .post() in my boot(router: Router) function

I have already looked through the Multipart vapor docs and read through these stackoverflow posts but still don't understand what I should be doing when I try to use the post method:
- [Vapor upload multiple files at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131593/vapor-upload-multiple-files-at-once)
- [How to handle multipart request with Vapor 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49489067/how-to-handle-multipart-request-with-vapor-3)
- [Image Upload in Vapor 3 using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476048/image-upload-in-vapor-3-using-postgresql)

This is my model class:

```
import Vapor
import FluentMySQL

final class AppObject: Codable {
  var id: Int?
  var plistFile: String // file
  var imageFile: String // file
  var notes: String
  var name: String

  init(ipaFile: String, plistFile: String, imageFile: String, notes: String, name: String) {
    self.ipaFile = ipaFile
    self.plistFile = plistFile
    self.imageFile = imageFile
    self.notes = notes
    self.name = name
  }
}

extension AppObject: MySQLModel {}
extension AppObject: Content {}
extension AppObject: Migration {}
extension AppObject: Parameter {}
```

This is my Controller for the above model:

```
import Vapor
import Fluent

struct AppObjectsController: RouteCollection {


    func boot(router: Router) throws {
        let appObjectsRoute = router.grouped("api", "apps")
        appObjectsRoute.get(use: getAllHandler)
        appObjectsRoute.post(AppObject.self, use: createHandler)
    }

    func getAllHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[AppObject]> {
        return AppObject.query(on: req).all()
    }

    // what else should I be doing here in order to upload actual files?
    func createHandler(_ req: Request, appobject: AppObject) throws -> Future<AppObject> {
         return appobject.save(on: req)
    }
}
```

some of the examples i've seen deal with uploading for a web app and they return a Future< View > but since I am doing an iOS app, I don't know if I should be returning an HTTPResponseStatus or my model object.

Please help, I tried my best to word this well, I am new to Vapor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Server-side

**Model**

```swift
final class AppObject: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var ipaFile: String // relative path to file in Public dir
    var plistFile: String // relative path to file in Public dir
    var imageFile: String // relative path to file in Public dir
    var notes: String
    var name: String

    init(ipaFile: String, plistFile: String, imageFile: String, notes: String, name: String) {
        self.ipaFile = ipaFile
        self.plistFile = plistFile
        self.imageFile = imageFile
        self.notes = notes
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension AppObject: MySQLModel {}
extension AppObject: Content {}
extension AppObject: Migration {}
extension AppObject: Parameter {}
```

**Controller**

```swift
struct AppObjectsController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(router: Router) throws {
        let appObjectsRoute = router.grouped("api", "apps")
        appObjectsRoute.get(use: getAllHandler)
        appObjectsRoute.post(PostData.self, use: createHandler)
    }

    func getAllHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[AppObject]> {
        return AppObject.query(on: req).all()
    }
}

extension AppObjectsController {
    struct PostData: Content {
        let ipaFile, plistFile, imageFile: File
        let name, notes: String
    }

    func createHandler(_ req: Request, payload: PostData) throws -> Future<AppObject> {
        let ipaFile = ServerFile(ext: "ipa", folder: .ipa)
        let plistFile = ServerFile(ext: "plist", folder: .plist)
        let imageFile = ServerFile(ext: "jpg", folder: .image)
        let appObject = AppObject(ipaFile: ipaFile.relativePath, plistFile: plistFile.relativePath, imageFile: imageFile.relativePath, notes: payload.notes, name: payload.name)
        /// we have to wrap it in transaction
        /// to rollback object creating
        /// in case if file saving fails
        return req.transaction(on: .mysql) { conn in
            return appObject.create(on: conn).map { appObject in
                try ipaFile.save(with: payload.ipaFile.data)
                try plistFile.save(with: payload.plistFile.data)
                try imageFile.save(with: payload.imageFile.data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ServerFile struct**

```swift
struct ServerFile {
    enum Folder: String {
        case ipa = "ipa"
        case plist = "plists"
        case image = "images"
        case root = ""
    }

    let file, ext: String
    let folder: Folder

    init (file: String? = UUID().uuidString, ext: String, folder: Folder? = .root) {
        self.file = file
        self.ext = ext
        self.folder = folder
    }

    var relativePath: String {
        guard folder != .root else { return fileWithExt }
        return folder.rawValue + "/" + fileWithExt
    }

    var fileWithExt: String { return file + "." + ext }

    func save(with data: Data) throws {
        /// Get path to project's dir
        let workDir = DirectoryConfig.detect().workDir
        /// Build path to Public folder
        let publicDir = workDir.appending("Public")
        /// Build path to file folder
        let fileFolder = publicDir + "/" + folder.rawValue
        /// Create file folder if needed
        var isDir : ObjCBool = true
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileFolder, isDirectory: &isDir) {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: fileFolder, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
        }
        let filePath = publicDir + "/" + relativePath
        /// Save data into file
        try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    }
}
```

### iOS

Declare `AppObject` model

```swift
struct AppObject: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var ipaFile, plistFile, imageFile: String
    var name, notes: String
}
```

With [CodyFire](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/CodyFire) library multipart requests are really easy

Declare you endpoint

```swift
import CodyFire

struct AppController: EndpointController {
    static var server: ServerURL? = nil
    static var endpoint: String = "apps"
}

/// Usually separate file like App+Create.swift
extension AppController {
    struct CreateAppRequest: MultipartPayload {
        var ipaFile, plistFile, imageFile: Attachment
        var name, note: String
        public init (ipaFile: Attachment, plistFile: Attachment, imageFile: Attachment, name: String, note: String) {
            self.ipaFile = ipaFile
            self.plistFile = plistFile
            self.imageFile = imageFile
            self.name = name
            self.note = note
        }
    }

    static func create(_ payload: CreateAppRequest) -> APIRequest<AppObject> {
        return request(payload: payload).method(.post)
    }
}
```

Then in some view controller try to create an app on the server

```swift
/// Replace _ with file data
let ipaFile = Attachment(data: _, fileName: "", mimeType: "ipa")
let plistFile = Attachment(data: _, fileName: "", mimeType: "plist")
let imageFile = Attachment(data: _, fileName: "", mimeType: .jpg)

let payload = AppController.CreateAppRequest(ipaFile: ipaFile, 
                                             plistFile: plistFile,
                                             imageFile: imageFile,
                                             name: "something", 
                                             note: "something")

AppController.create(payload).onRequestStarted {
    /// it calls only if request started properly
    /// start showing loading bar
}.onError { error in
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: error.description, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}.onProgress { progress in
    /// show progress
}.onSuccess { appObject in
    /// show success
    /// here you received just created `appObject`
}
```

And that's it, it just works :)

Next example for getting list of `AppObject`s

```swift
/// Separate file like App+List.swift
extension AppController {
    static func list() -> APIRequest<[AppObject]> {
        return request()
    }
}
```

then somewhere in view controller

```swift
AppController.list().onSuccess { appObjects in
    /// `appObjects` is `[AppObject]`
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much @imike!! I did have to change the `PostData` struct to conform to `Content` instead of `Codable` and then I had to return the appObject within the closure where you call `appObject.create(on: conn).map { ... }` but everything else was spot on. 

My next challenge is saving this onto an actual server like AWS S3 but you helped clarify a lot of things, if you could shoot me any resources you used to learn this in greater detail I would appreciate it since I would have never guessed to create a ServerFile struct, thanks!!

Comment: I'm really happy to help, my pleasure :) please feel free to find me in Discord as iMike#3049